# Finding the distance to the next patch ahead of a given color in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to model predators hunting prey through a world filled with obstacles. In an obstacle free world, the predators go on random walks until prey fall within a certain detection radius (react-D), and then move towards the prey to capture. I guess there may be several ways to handle obstacles that block line of sight, but my initial efforts are along the following lines:

```
ifelse any? prey in-radius react-D
[let target min-one-of prey in-radius react-D [distance myself]
 face target
 ...move towards target if it's closer than the nearest obstacle (blue patch) ahead
]
[continue to random walk, avoiding obstacles
]
```

The first condition of ifelse may need another ifelse. In any case I think I just need a distance of the nearest blue patch ahead to compare with the target distance, but it's not clear to me how I can get that from `patch-ahead`.
It would be nicer if I could put all this into the test of the first ifelse, but something like the following doesn't allow for patches that aren't blocking line of sight to the prey:

```
 ifelse any? prey in-radius react-D and min-one-of (patches in-radius react-D with [pcolor = blue])[distance myself] >   min-one-of (prey in-radius react-D) [distance myself]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current solution, giving `patches-own [ ob ]` values of 1 to all obstacle patches, then using while to detect obstacles ahead:

```
to detect-ahead
let dist 1
  let last-patch patch-here
  while [dist <= react-D] [
    let p patch-ahead dist
    if p != last-patch and [ob] of p = 1 [
      ask p [ sprout-markers 1 [ set color yellow ] ] 
      set last-patch p
    ]
    set dist dist + 1
  ]
end
```

Then it should simply be a case of comparing `min-one-of` the marker agent set with the target. Obviously smaller increments would be good, as JenB says.

Answer (score 2):

Line of sight is actually really tricky to model in NetLogo. At the moment I do it by creating a turtle (invisible, separate breed called crawler) where the agent is that is looking and have the crawler move ahead in small steps checking the colour of the patch that it is on. That goes inside a while loop and the crawler stops when it finds the wrong colour or when it gets to the target distance. the crawler has to take small steps because crossing over the corner of a patch should still block it and it's a trade-off between resolution (how small the crawler step is) against efficiency.

You can almost certainly do the same thing by creating a `patch-set` as the union of `patches` found with `patch-ahead` of multiple distances like 0.1, 0.2, .... and then checking `any?` over that patch-set

Comment: This has put me on the right track thanks. I found a netlogo line of sight example model and edited it up a bit, giving `patches-own [ ob ]` values of 1 to all obstacle patches, then using while as you suggest.